# haskell how to [a]++ [b] with maybe

Tags: haskell

I would like do `Maybe Substitution -> Maybe Substitution -> Maybe Substitution`
where `type Substitution = [(Variable,Terme)]` but when I use `++` I have this

```
/Users/michel/Documents/workspace/2LammensMichelInterpreteurProlog/Setup.hs:65:58:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘[a0]’
                with actual type ‘Maybe Substitution’
    In the first argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘listsub’
    In the expression: listsub ++ listsub

/Users/michel/Documents/workspace/2LammensMichelInterpreteurProlog/Setup.hs:65:58:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Maybe Substitution’
                with actual type ‘[a0]’
    In the expression: listsub ++ listsub
    In an equation for ‘substition’:
        substition ((V variable), (F nom1 lTerme1)) listsub
          = listsub ++ listsub

/Users/michel/Documents/workspace/2LammensMichelInterpreteurProlog/Setup.hs:65:69:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘[a0]’
                with actual type ‘Maybe Substitution’
    In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘listsub’
    In the expression: listsub ++ listsub
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: Based on the error, you're trying to concatenate two things but at least one of them isn't a list. Check to make sure they're lists before using `++`.

Answer (score 1):

`(++)` works on lists, not `Maybe`'s, you need to lift it

Here is how you can make it work on `Maybe String`.

```
import Control.Monad
(liftM2 (++)) (Just "aa") (Just "bb")
```

You can make this look nicer by defining a new operator.

```
(+++) = liftM2 (++)
```

then use it like

```
Just "aa" +++ Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

`Maybe` is an Applicative, so you can use functions such as `liftA2` to apply functions to values within `Maybe`s.

For example (if your variables and terms were strings):

```
import Control.Applicative

liftA2 (++) (Just [("foo", "bar")])  (Just [("FOO", "BAR")])
-- Just [("foo","bar"),("FOO","BAR")]
```

or equivalently, using the `<$>` and `<*>` infix operators:

```
(++) <$> Just [("foo", "bar")]  <*> Just [("FOO", "BAR")]
-- Just [("foo","bar"),("FOO","BAR")]
```

See http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids